# Mqtt client in multiple interface

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to connect to a mqtt broker with mqtt-client. My PC is connected to two different network interface (ethernet and wifi)

Apparently `paho-mqtt` provides a way to select interface through "bind_address". [paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#connect-reconnect-disconnect)

```
connect(host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
```

[image]

Seems like it's failing (time_out) even with the bind address when used in this way.

```
connect(host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="192.168.xxx.xxx")
```

Error Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stream.py", line 105, in <module>
    client.connect(MQTT_IP, bind_address="192.168.0.215")
  File "/media/mmrbulbul/HDD2/reid_codes/conv_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/media/mmrbulbul/HDD2/reid_codes/conv_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1044, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/media/mmrbulbul/HDD2/reid_codes/conv_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3685, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=self._connect_timeout, source_address=source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Since it's a timeout error are you 100% sure there is no firewall dropping packets on the network you have bound to?

Comment: Checked that as well.
The mqtt fails when both wifi and LAN are enabled. But works when only wifi is connected. 
Suspecting this is not a mqtt issue rather networking issue.

Comment: Yep, check what routes are setup in both cases

Comment: Checked the default IP route and it’s not conflicting.

Comment: Not that they conflict, but that you can actually reach the broker via which ever default route has the lowest metric value.

Comment: Thanks. That helped and apparently that was the problem.